# Conditions for smooth dependence of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix on a set of parameters

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, eigenvector, matrices, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials

Let $A\in\mathcal M_n$ be an $n\times n$ real [symmetric] matrix which depends smoothly on a [finite] set of parameters, $A=A(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k)$. We can view it as a smooth function $A:\mathbb R^k\to\mathcal M_n$.

> 1. What conditions should the matrix $A$ satisfy so that its eigenvalues
>   $\lambda_i(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k)$,
>   $i=1,\ldots,n$, depend smoothly on the
>   parameters $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k$?

*e.g.* if the characteristic equation is $\lambda^3-\xi=0$, then the solution $\lambda_1=\sqrt[3] \xi$ is not derivable at $\xi=0$.

> 2. What additional conditions should the matrix $A$ satisfy so that we can
>   choose a set of eigenvectors
>   $v_i(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k)$,
>   $i=1,\ldots,n$, which depend smoothly
>   on the parameters
>   $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k$?

**Update - important details**

- The domain is simply connected
- The rank of $A$ can change in the domain
- The multiplicities of the eigenvalues can change in the domain, they can cross
- The matrix $A$ is real symmetric
- $n$ and $k$ are finite

**Update 2**

- A relaxation of the conditions of the problem:
  For fixed $p=(\xi_{01},\ldots,\xi_{0k})$, can we find an open neighborhood of $p$ in the domain and a set of conditions ensuring the smoothness of the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors?

Comment: You want something different from the conditions coming out of the implicit function theorem applied to the characteristic polynomial of $A$ for (1) and the corresponding equation for eigenvalues for (2)?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez
I think that the implicit function theorem helps. But I couldn't see a straight solution.

Comment: Cristi, you really should have mentioned the "real symmetric" part to begin with; a lot of the worries associated with such problems disappear.

Comment: @J. M. you are right, sorry about this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fact that the entries of the matrix are real does seem to help. The state of the art is the following.

- The spectrum is continuous functions of $\xi$. However, it is not always possible to label the eigenvalues so that they individually are continuous functions.
- When the multiplicities $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ do not change as $\xi$ varies (no crossing of eigenvalues), then the eigenvalues are as smooth as the matrix. If the domain is simply connected, the eigenvalues may be labelled so as to be smooth functions.
- When the entries are analytic functions of a *single* variable ($k=1$) and the eigenvalues remain real, then the eigenvalues may be labelled so as to be analytic functions. However, in case of crossing, this nice labelling is not the obvious one (*i.e.* not $\lambda_1\le\lambda_1\le\cdots$). This become false for $k\ge 2$, as shown by the example 
  $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \xi_1 & \xi_2 \\\\ \xi_2 & -\xi_1 \end{array}\right)\qquad\qquad (1).$$
- The situation is not that good concerning the eigenvectors. The following is called *Petrowski's example*,
  $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & \xi_1 & \xi_1 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\  \xi_1 & 0 &  \xi_2  \end{array}\right).$$
  The eigenvalues are real for every $\xi$, distinct when $ \xi_1\ne0$. The matrix is diagonalisable for every $\xi$, but two eigenvectors have the same limit when $ \xi_1\rightarrow0$.

If the domain is not simply connected, you may have additional difficulties with eigenvectors. Take example (1) above, with $\xi$ running over the unit circle $S^1$. When you follow continuously a unit eigenvector $V(\xi)$, it is flipped (*i.e.* multiplied by $-1$) after one loop

Comment: I had troubles with the edit of my answer. Thus I deleted it and repost it. Hopefully, it appears only once. If not, please forgive me.

Comment: @Denis Serre

Thank you. Your answer made me add some details that may be critical, but I omitted.

- if the domain is simply connected, can the eigenvalues be labeled as distinct functions, even if their multiplicities change?

- if the matrix $A$ is symmetric, can we "save" the eigenvectors?

Thank you

Comment: Note that Denis's first example is a symmetric matrix. An example of a symmetric matrix that shows how the eigenvectors can be very sensitive to changes in matrix entries is due to Wallace Givens: `$\begin{pmatrix}1+\epsilon\cos\left(\frac2{\epsilon}\right)&\epsilon\sin\left(\frac2{\epsilon}\right)\\ \epsilon\sin\left(\frac2{\epsilon}\right)&1-\epsilon\cos\left(\frac2{\epsilon}\right)\end{pmatrix}$`

Comment: @Cristi. I doubt that it is possible in general. Suppose that there is one complex parameter $z$, and $A(z)$ is holomorphic in $z$. At a branching point, where eigenvalues cross, they form a Riemann surface with non-trivial monodromy. Now, you can write $z=\xi_1+i\xi_2$ and view $A(z)$ as a $(2n)\times(2n)$ matrix, so the trouble applies also to some real matrices.

Comment: @J. M. Yes, these are good counterexamples. Maybe there are some conditions under which the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are smooth, at least in the case when the matrix is real and symmetric and the domain simply connected.

Comment: @Denis Serre. Thanks again. Yes, I am aware that it is not possible in general, and I am just looking for some conditions, as I asked in the original question. I think that I was not careful when I formulated the comment from above. My hope is that for symmetric real matrices and small enough neighborhood of each point in the domain there can be some simple conditions. I am happy with necessary conditions if they are general enough to allow change of the multiplicity. I will continue to think at this problem and I will wait answers for a while. Your answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

See the following papers by Armin Rainer (et al):

Perturbation theory for normal operators. [arXiv:1111.4475](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4475)

Quasianalytic multiparameter perturbation of polynomials and normal matrices.
[arXiv:0905.0837](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0837).

Denjoy-Carleman differentiable perturbation of polynomials and unbounded operators. Integral Equations and Operator Theory 71,3 (2011), 407-416.
[arXiv:0910.0155](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0155)