# Regularity of decomposition of matrix-valued function

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Here is the problem. Suppose I have a positive definite matrix-valued function $A\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then we know that there is a matrix-valued function $B\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A=B^TB$, where $B^T$ is the transpose of $B$. I wonder if $A\in C^k$, what is the best possible regularity of the matrix $B$? More precisely, if $A\in C^0$ or $A\in L^\infty$, is it true that $B\in L^\infty$ as well?

If one tries to diagonalized by smooth similarity transformations, then it might not work; see

[Can always a family of symmetric real matrices depending smoothly on a real parameter be diagonalized by smooth similarity transformations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60533/can-always-a-family-of-symmetric-real-matrices-depending-smoothly-on-a-real-para)

Comment: The square root of $A$ is well defined, and has the same regularity as $A$.

Comment: @abx: It is not very clear to me, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60533/can-always-a-family-of-symmetric-real-matrices-depending-smoothly-on-a-real-para somewhat surprisingly.

Comment: The keyword here is *positive*.

Comment: @abx: Is there a simple proof of this fact without using diagonalization to diagonal matrix?

Comment: See [Square root of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @abx: Can you make your reference more precise? I do not find there the statement that for a matrix valued functin if you take pointwise square root then the regularity of the function remains.

Comment: This is just the elementary fact that the map $A\mapsto\sqrt{A}$ is (real) analytic in the open cone of positive definite symmetric matrices.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: this can be seen from the spectral decomposition of positive definite matrix. Namely, write $A=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i P_i(A)$, then $g(A)=\sum_{i=1}^ng(\lambda_i)P_i(A)$, which can be found in standard linear algebra book. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you apply the Cholesky algorithm leading to the matrix $B$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition. It will follow that the smoothness class of $B$ will be the class obtained from the smoothness class of $A$ by applying several times the square root operation to positive functions (this operation clearly may reduce smoothness of functions). In the case of classes $C^0$ or $L^\infty$, they will be preserved.